# Trouble connecting to postgresql via JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to the postgressql server hosted in the same computer from JDBC, but can see nothing printed on the console, not even the exception. Here is the code for the same

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Before connection");  //This is getting printed
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:53574/","postgres","**");
            System.out.println("After connection");  //This is not getting printed
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After entering the correct password, phrase `Before connection` is getting printed while `After connection` is not getting printed. I tried changing the port number and only then the exception
`Connection to localhost:5357 refused` is caught.

Please help me figure out the mistake I'm making. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you've specified the name of your database.  I'd expect your connection string to look something like `"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:53574/mydatabase"`

Comment: The question should include the error you're getting. But first Google the error message, there are lots of these questions already.

Comment: @NathanHughes there is no error message. That's the main problem

Comment: Is a stack trace being printed? `e.printStackTrace(System.out);` also might sometimes be usefull, as otherwise to `System.err` is printed, which might mix up console's lines as `out` and `err` are not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check whether your port number is wrong(default port number is 5432 not 5357)
or you can use `netstat -ntlp` to check what port is open on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

### Reasons

- Driver is not available.
- Nothing is listening on the Port you are
- Postgresql isn't running.
- Postgresql isn't listening for TCP/IP connections.
- Postgresql is listening on a different port to the
  one you're connecting on.

When the Postgresql server daemon is not running in the server, it can trigger connection refused error. At the same time, several other reasons can also trigger this error.

When you are scanning ports 1 to 65535, this is expected to happen with most ports. It's a sign that you should move on to the next port.

### Solution

**Download Latest PostgreSQL JDBC Driver**

To connect to the PostgreSQL database server from a Java program, you need to have PostgreSQL JDBC driver. You can download the latest version of the driver on the postgresql.org website via the download page.
The downloaded file is a jar file. You should copy it to a specific folder e.g. C:\demo\libs so that you can remember its location and be able to add it to your Java application later.

Then , add the PostgreSQL JDBC driver jar file to the project.

To import jar file in your Eclipse IDE, follow the steps given below.

1. List item
2. Right click on your project
3. Select Build Path
4. Click on Configure Build Path
5. Click on Libraries and select Add External JARs
6. Select the jar file from the required folder
7. Click and Apply and Ok

then, you need to prepare the following:

1. The address of the PostgreSQL database server
2. The database name
3. The username and password of the account that you will use to connect to the database.

For this information, you can construct the PostgreSQL JDBC connection string by using the following format:

To make it easier, we can define the attributes of the App class for storing connection string, user, and password:

```
private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename";
private final String user = "yourname";
private final String password = "yourpassword";
```

Code should look like this

**MainClass.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainClass {

private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename";
private final String user = "yourname";
private final String password = "yourpassword";

public Connection connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();
    app.connect();
}
```

}

**Run a port scan**

make sure the port is opened. To show all connections

Open cmd and enter following command and hit enter

```
netstat -a
```

You will see all the active connections from different states as shown below.

You need to edit postgresql.conf (inside your data directory) to set the new port there, then restart the postgresql service using the Services control panel or (as an Administrator) the net service command.

**Edit postgresql.conf**

This file is usually located in /var/lib/pgsql/data/ on Linux or C:\PostgreSQL\data\ on Windows or similar.
In this file we will edit the "listen_address" and "port" parameters, so that they look like below:

**Connection Settings**

```
listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'        # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
```

**Steps:**

1. Go to..\postgresql\9.0\data and open the file postgresql.conf in text editor/notepad
2. Search for port parameter .eg: port = 5433
3. Edit this to your port number.
4. Go to run type services.msc and restart postgresql service.

**Restart PostgreSQL**

After that we need to restart PostgreSQL to activate the changes.

On Windows you can use Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services and find service named postgres then restart the PostgreSQL service by right click -> properties - >stop then start.

Answer (score 0):

Consistent timeouts on connection attempt are almost always a firewall issue.  Since you are connecting to localhost, it must be an internal firewall.  You need to change your firewall to let 53574 through.  Or since you know 5357 is getting through, maybe just run it there.  53574 is a strange port to run a database server on, anyway.

Presumably it doesn't matter that you connecting with Java, you could get the same behavior out of psql or psycopg2.